# How to store data sequentially in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity called `OperationEntity`. It has a to-many relationship to `OperationInput`.

[image]

I have a table view controller that displays all the `OperationEntity` that are saved. When the user taps on one of the cells, a segue that goes to another table view controller is performed. That table view controller displays all the associated `OperationInput` of `OperationEntity`.

In the `NSManagedObject` subclasses that Xcode has generated for me, the `availableInputs` property is declared to be of type `NSSet?`. I know that sets don't maintain the order of its elements. This means that I might save the inputs in this order:

```
a
b
c
```

But when I fetch it back, I might get it in this order instead

```
c
a
b
```

but I want the inputs to be in the same order as they were saved!

How do I solve this problem?

I have thought of adding an `id` property to `OperationInput`. Each time I save a new one, I increment the id. When I fetch it, I sort the array according to the id. But I am sure there's a better way to do it than this.

Maybe changing `NSSet?` to `NSArray?` with brute force? That can't work, can it?

It is surprising that I have not found anyone asking the question on Stack Overflow!

Comment: This *has* been asked and answered before. You'll find more answers when searching for `[core-data] preserve order`.

Comment: @MartinR But that question seems really outdated. From Erik Johansson's answer, I can see that this can be done in a way better way than adding `id`s.

Comment: The accepted answer to the referenced question mentions the ordered relationship as well: *"If you can target iOS 5 then you can use the new NSOrderedSet feature for arbitrarily-ordered Core Data relationships"*. That is exactly what Erik suggested below. – Adding an id field is also a good solution and has it's advantages, as ordered relationships can be tricky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you select the relationship and look in the Data Model Inspector you have an option `arrangement`. If you set it you will have an NSOrderedSet which maintains order.

[image]

Comment: I have to generate the `NSManagedObject` subclasses again, right?

Comment: Yes or just update the existing one. Swap `NSSet` for `NSOrderedSet`

Comment: thanks sir ji my problem is solved.